# Null when passing array of int[] between activities with intent

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, null

I have seen several questions about this but I could not find what was the issue related to my own problem.

I am trying to pass several arrays of integers between a service and another activity using intents. I am also passing other int values which are not arrays. All my arrays are "Null" when received and I don't understand why

Passing Service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(UPDATE_ALL);
intent.putExtra(RAW_CELLS, rawCells);
intent.putExtra(RAW_CELLVL, rawCellsLevel);
intent.putExtra(RAW_CELASU, rawCellsAsuLevel);
intent.putExtra(RAW_CELDBM, rawCellsDbm);
```

Catching Activity:

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "intent.getExtras()="+intent.getExtras());
int rawCellsTotal = intent.getIntExtra(SensorService.RAW_CELLS, 0);
int[] rawCelLvl = intent.getExtras().getIntArray(SensorService.RAW_CELLVL);
int[] rawCelAsu = intent.getExtras().getIntArray(SensorService.RAW_CELASU);
int[] rawCelDbm = intent.getExtras().getIntArray(SensorService.RAW_CELDBM);
```

From the Log.d line, I can see this in logcat:

```
Bundle[{com.myapp.MyService.RAW_CELASL=[29, 7], com.myapp.MyService.RAW_CELDBM=[-111, -133], com.myapp.MyService.RAW_CELLVL=[2, 1], com.myapp.MyService.RAW_CELLS=2}]
```

Then when I debug the code, I can have a value in **rawCellsTotal** which is not an array but a simple integer (e.g. 2), but I always have 'Null' in **rawCelLvl**, **rawCelAsu**, **rawCelDbm** which are supposed to be arrays of integers with 2 values as shown in logcat.

Any tip to fix this?

**EDIT:**

I tried to change my code as follows in the service:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(UPDATE_ALL);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putIntegerArrayList(RAW_CELLVL, rawCellsLevel);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
```

and keeping the same code in the catching activity, but still the same result. Can you help me a bit with the correct way to use the Bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

intent.getExtras().getIntArray() -> Attempt to retrieve the array from the extras bundle.

you are not adding the extras bundle. You have to use:

intent.getByteArrayExtra() -> streight from the intent extras

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to put datas into a Bundle then put the bundle into the Intent because Bundle is created to be the container of data. You can manage them more easily.

In you case, you are getting `getIntArray(SensorService.RAW_CELLVL);`from the bundle which is empty.

P.S: when you call the method `getExtras()` you get an Bundle obj.

Comment: I added some changes I tried in the question, can you help me to have the correct Bundle syntax?

Comment: Of course, when you want to put a data into a Bundle, you can use: 'bundle.putString("VarName",strYouWantToPass)' if it is a String,  bundle.putInt("VarName1",5) if it is an Integer.
To get a data from a Bundle you can use get methods,
 Like:
String str=bundle.getString("varName"),
int number= bundle.getInt("VarName1").

Answer (score 1):

use getIntArrayExtra(String name)

```
int[] rawCelLvl = intent.getIntArrayExtra(SensorService.RAW_CELLVL);
int[] rawCelAsu = intent.getIntArrayExtra(SensorService.RAW_CELASU);
int[] rawCelDbm = intent.getIntArrayExtra(SensorService.RAW_CELDBM);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved the issue this morning, very similar to your proposal but using ArrayList<Integer> instead

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue:

```
intent.putExtra(RAW_CELLVL, rawCellsAsuLevel);
intent.putExtra(RAW_CELASU, rawCellsAsuLevel);
intent.putExtra(RAW_CELDBM, rawCellsDbm);
```

in the receiving Activity:

```
ArrayList<Integer> rawCelLvl = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra(SensorService.RAW_CELLVL);
ArrayList<Integer> rawCelAsu = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra(SensorService.RAW_CELASU);
ArrayList<Integer> rawCelDbm = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra(SensorService.RAW_CELDBM);
```

Thanks for all the replies, the clues on the Bundle and the fact that "Extras" <> "Extra" put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Check that array, you trying to cell is initialized correctly.

```
int[] ints = new int[SIZE];
```

or

```
int[] ints = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

NPE means that there is no array

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Custom class then you have to serialize the class. i.e implement class using Serializable class. If done so you can pass array from intent by just

```
intent.putExtra();
```

or you can just set that arrays to a class and pass object of the class

you can also create static class and set that class with your data so that you can receive data directly without passing object of that class.